# My Windows 8 app doesn't appear in other stores

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I developed a **windows 8 game**, and I can't find it on the other Stores.

Even If I changed the preference of the Windows store application ... no result for my application, I already checked all countries for my application on Dev Center - Windows Store apps.

How can I add a French description and screenshots for my app?

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: This isn't the right place to ask this question... not sure there is a stackexchange site that would be appropriate. You'll probably have better luck asking on some windows 8 developer forums.

Comment: Already did, I posted my question on msdn forum, but still unanswered until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for Multilanguage Support

How to use the Multilingual App Toolkit (Windows): 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj569303.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The ability to add French metadata (like a description and screenshots for your app) won't be available until after you upload your app package which specifies French language support.  (Here's a [source verifying this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsstore/thread/340d3c3f-05a9-4342-b274-ee4d6a9ba7c4).)

For how to properly implement localization support in your app, see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/16/common-windows-store-certification-errors-6-5-app-must-be-localized.aspx) which explains the basics and provides localization resources compiled in one place.